# How to learn correct pronunciation of phrases

Tags: self-learning, resource-request, pronunciation

Some dictionaries providing transcriptions for some words. Some online dictionaries even provide a sound file for a single word.

However it is sometimes useful to have a source of a **phrase** pronounced by the native speakers.

So is there anything available on the Web?

**UPDATE**

I've found a good resource as well: [tatoeba.org](https://tatoeba.org)

Comment: You can always put them in Google Translate.

Comment: @GiaFil7 sometimes it is too robotic. This is why I looked for alternatives.

Answer (score 4):

[RhinoSpike](https://rhinospike.com/) is a good resource for this sort of thing. You can upload the text you wish to hear, and a native speaker will record the phrase for you. In exchange, you will be expected to record texts in your native language, as well.